# How to connect REST API built using Django Rest Framework with Flutter app

Tags: django, flutter, django-rest-framework

I am building an application to register details of user for which I have used Django rest framework for backend and Flutter for frontend. I am having no idea on connecting these two. Please help me.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the django framework . Look at this example https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Answer (score 1):

An API is an API, it does not matter what language or framework it was built in.
All you need to do is to make request and get response(in JSON or XML).

You can follow some of this tutorials on how to make HTTP requests to APIs.

- https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xfdG8e9mgU4
- https://medium.com/flutter-community/working-with-apis-in-flutter-8745968103e9
- https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-make-http-requests-in-flutter-d12e98ee1cef
- https://kodestat.gitbook.io/flutter/flutter-http-requests-and-rest-api
- https://blog.codeminer42.com/build-your-first-app-with-flutter-getting-data-from-api-c9fb4c2a6812

Good luck with your app!

Comment: Thank you so much for this wonderful list of publications. I met the same challenge like topic starter, and your help is very valuable for mee too. Do you have another lists on some aspects of Flutter? For now, I am interested mostly in authentication with different backends.

Answer (score 0):

The best way you can develop your APP its to try and keep both parts separate and then make it work together through the HTTP protocol and its methods.

Some things to consider on the `Flutter` + `DRF` combination:

- Always let the logical process of querying this against the main DATABASE to DRF serializers and views, and develop models on your frontend to use with a Sqlite integrated DB on the frontend, helping your server to manage its load if the app scale is high and with many users.
- Try to read the docs of the DRF carefully, and use the tools that this framework provides you. They are in most cases, much more optimized than the Python standard code, and just override strictly the things that you need.
- If you are alone developing both frontend and backend, first design the pattern that you need to satisfy what you need, and then try to make the schema of your frontend before you even start to write your backend. Avoid putting things in your Front End, just think about what you will design and what you will need.
- And finally, if you are coding to learn, try to enjoy every step along the way, and try to learn a nice way to have fun along your travels.

Hope it won't be too late! :)